# behavior of '== 'with objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, operators

I know the difference between '==' and '===' 
please correct me if i am wrong '==' operators check for value correct i.e. it does coercion? and '===' check for value and type both?
but i dont understand how i get the following result please have a look:

```
var a= new String("one");
var b= new String("one");

a==b  // I expected it to be true but it is FALSE please explain both the objects have same value then why?
```

From the thread provided by Felix i could gather that
 '==' behaves differently for reference types and primitive types i.e. it does coercion if one of the operand is a primitive but if both are objects then it only compares reference . Then can i conclude that in case both the operands are reference types like above, '==' and '===' work exactly same?

Comment: because they are not the same object reference.

Comment: `a` and `b` are referencing different objects, therefore it's false. That's why you never use `new String` or `new Number` or `new Boolean`, etc., because they will mess up your code.

Comment: *"Then can i conclude that in case both the operands are reference types like above, '==' and '===' work exactly same?"* Yes.

Answer (score 2):

That's because you comparing object reference, you can have a great understanding by reading the last part of this [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)..

This is like yours:

```
// fruit object reference variable
var fruit = {name: "apple"};

// fruitbear object reference variable
var fruitbear = {name: "apple"};

fruit == fruitbear // return false

fruit === fruitbear // return false
```

The is what you should do to get true:

```
// fruit object reference variable
var fruit = {name: "apple"};

// fruitbear object reference variable
var fruitbear = fruit;  // assign fruit object reference to fruitbear object reference variable

// here fruit and fruitbear pointing to same object called fruit
fruit == fruitbear // return true

// here fruit and fruitbear pointing to same object called fruit
fruit === fruitbear // return true
```

Comment: sorry cant accept as answer i found the actual answer in the above  thread which says '==' behaves differently when one of the operand is primitive types and other is reference type i.e. coercion of reference type  happens but if both are reference types it only checks reference not the values.

Comment: No probs, we're here to help people.. ^^